# download CAS server for jetty

Tags: jetty, cas

Where can I download a war file to install the [CAS server](https://apereo.github.io/cas) in a jetty instance?

On the official [downloads page](https://github.com/apereo/cas/releases) I only find sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [very same link](https://apereo.github.io/cas) that you referenced, there is a "Getting Started" section under which there is "Installation". That page describes the installation process and how that works in general and points you to the installation script/project that is [here](https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template). Download that project and follow the instructions on the readme. In particular, you'll find in the gradle.properties file of that project,

```
# Use -jetty, -undertow to other containers
# Or blank if you want to deploy to an external container
appServer=-tomcat
```

So you'd set:

```
appServer=
```

For your external container of choice, such as jetty.

Or you'd set:

```
appServer=-jetty
```

For an embedded Jetty container.

Comment: I also had to add 'org.gradle.java.home=...', since my default Java was not version 11.
default user and password is: casuser Mellon